# Getting error pipeline@tmp/durable-81eb936b/script.sh: line 5: command not found

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm creating a pipeline in jenkins to build a binary using ANT. After creating I'm using some shell commands to store md5sum of the generated war file. But when using the shell commands I'm getting error.

```
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                    //sh "ant -f ABC/XYZ/build.xml build"
                    withAnt(installation: 'ANT_1.9.9', jdk: 'Java_1.8.0_361') {
                        sh 'ant  -f ABC/XYZ/build.xml build'
                        
                    }
                    sh 'SUM=echo $(md5sum ${WORKSPACE}/ABC/XYZ/dist/ABC.war)'
                    sh 'echo $SUM'
                    
            }

            post {
                success {
                    echo "build success"
                }
            }


        }
```

I'm getting below error
++ md5sum /opt/codecheckout/pipeline/ABC/XYZ/dist/ABC.war

- SUM=echo
- 4ffaf00d7fa7dbd0398d9d4de3496992 /opt/codecheckout/pipeline/ABC/XYZ/ABC.war
  /opt/codecheckout/pipeline@tmp/durable-0f835202/script.sh: line 1: 4ffaf00d7fa7dbd0398d9d4de3496992: command not found

I have tried using script syntax in pipeline as well, but getting the same error.

```
                        sh script:'''
                        #!/bin/bash
                        SUM=$(md5sum ${WORKSPACE}/ABC/XYZ/ABC.war)
                        echo $SUM
                        MDSUM= "$(echo $SUM | head -n1 | awk '{print $1;}')"
                        //echo $MDSUM
                        '''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue actual is about Bash syntax.

```
SUM=echo $(md5sum ${WORKSPACE}/ABC/XYZ/dist/ABC.war)

# there is a space between "echo" and 
"SUM=echo $(md5sum ${WORKSPACE}/ABC/XYZ/dist/ABC.war)"

thus Bash interpreter will treat the line into two parts:
1) SUM=echo 
  the first part work well 

2) $(md5sum ${WORKSPACE}/ABC/XYZ/dist/ABC.war) 
   the second part return the md5 sum which is a string, then bash continue 
   treat it as a cmd and execute it (the md5 string: 4ffaf00d7fa7dbd0398d9d4de3496992),
   but the md5 string is not a bash cmd or executable. 

   that's why the error say "4ffaf00d7fa7dbd0398d9d4de3496992: command not found"
```

Fix your issue is simple

```
SUM=$(md5sum ${WORKSPACE}/ABC/XYZ/dist/ABC.war)
// the ahead echo is unnecessary
or 
SUM=$(echo $(md5sum ${WORKSPACE}/ABC/XYZ/dist/ABC.war))
```

Answer (score 0):

My Problem is with `CRLF` and `LF` Line Endings.
I wrote the script on Windows and tried to execute it on a linux node.
So I converted the Line Endings in my Jenkinsfile before executing the script:

```
sh '''
   sed -i 's/\r$//' script.sh
'''
sh "./script.sh"
```